# Making dynamic command line requests to node.js

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have this file called environment.config.js that takes locale, language, and theme as arguments in the command line and runs it to generate files accordingly:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const copydir = require("copy-dir");

if (process.argv.length < 5) {
  console.log(process.argv);
  console.error("Missing arguments!");
  process.exit(1);
}

const LOCALE = process.argv[2];
const LANG = process.argv[3];
const THEME = process.argv[4];

const wording = require(`./src/locales/${LOCALE}/i18n/${LANG}.json`);
fs.writeFileSync("./src/locales/main/wording.json", JSON.stringify(wording, undefined, 2));

const theme = require(`./src/locales/${LOCALE}/theme/${THEME}.json`);
fs.writeFileSync("./src/locales/main/colors.json", JSON.stringify(theme, undefined, 2));

const assets_dir = `./src/locales/${LOCALE}/assets`;
copydir(assets_dir, "./src/locales/main/assets", (err) =>
  err ? console.log(err) : console.log("Assets written successfully!")
);
```

And inside package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "locale:spotify": "node environment.config spotify",
    "locale:youtube": "node environment.config youtube",
    "spotify:dark": "npm run locale:spotify en dark && expo start",
    "spotify:light": "npm run locale:spotify en light && expo start",
    "spotify:fr:dark": "npm run locale:spotify fr dark && expo start",
    "spotify:fr:light": "npm run locale:spotify fr light && expo start",
    "youtube:dark": "npm run locale:youtube en dark && expo start",
    "youtube:light": "npm run locale:youtube en light && expo start",
    "youtube:fr:dark": "npm run locale:youtube fr dark && expo start",
    "youtube:fr:light": "npm run locale:youtube fr light && expo start"
  },
  ...
}
```

So if I wanna have a dark Spotify version of the app in French, I run "yarn start spotify:fr:dark" and it does the magic. So my question is, how can I make all of these dynamically produced? Is there any way I can get rid of "spotify:dark", "spotify:light", "spotify:fr:dark", etc etc and have 1 key that does the process dynamically?

For example: when I run `npm run youtube:fr:light`, it should automatically take the keywords "youtube", "fr" and "light" as variables and replace the script like so: `npm run locale:LOCALE LANG THEME && expo start`, I don't know how but you got the point. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use [yarn args](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run/), like `yarn locale -spotify -fr -dark` ?

Comment: @ViktorGusev Ok sure, that works too but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: I didn't get you right then. Can you please rephrase your question? How do you want this 1 key to look like?

Comment: something like so? npm run youtube -- -fr -dark , scripts: ... "youtube": "node environment.config youtube", "postyoutube": "expo start"

Comment: @Estradiaz how are "fr" and "dark" being passed to "youtube"? I'm logging the argvs and they're not showing there. Your answer is close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: It should be `npm run <command> [-- <args>]` not sure why argv is empty ?

Comment: @Estradiaz I used `"youtube": "node environment.config youtube && expo start"` in package.json and ran `npm run spotify -- -fr -light`, correct?